# ¿Como puedo guardar un usuario en localStorage si el login pasa la validación?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Hola básicamente estoy un poco mareado a la hora de guardar en el localStorage un user, ya que necesito guardar el token y el user para persistir durante la sesión. Con el token me resulto simple pero me complica esta función:

```
inLoggin(user, token) {

   const tokenRecibido = res.data.token;
   localStorage.setItem('token', tokenRecibido);
```

}

let token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

como verán localStorage lo esta asignando pero no se como hacerlo con user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que todo lo que guardas en el localStorage deben ser valores diferentes a un objeto. Por lo tanto, si lo que buscas es guardar un usuario de tipo objeto, primero debes convertirlo a string y luego ya guardarlo. Para ello usa el método JSON.stringify(user), así convertirás el objeto a formato de texto y podrás guardarlo. Si quieres leerlo de vuelta usa JSON.parse(user). Espero haberte ayudado.

```
// Guardar usuario
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));

//Leer usuario
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido